# Windows 7 laptop takes 15 minutes after startup before it's usable

Tags: windows-7, diagnostic

Up until about a year ago, the laptop was great. But now it just seems to take forever after startup to be usable, like open up a browser. It will show the desktop, but other than tracking the cursor, it's unresponsive, even Ctrl-Alt-Delete to open task manager doesn't do anything until maybe 10 minutes in. When it opens, windows task manager and resource monitor indicate less than 5% CPU, no significant disk activity, no significant network activity, no indication that the laptop is doing anything other than being a stupid lump of silicon.

Based on other feedback on SO, I've uninstalled MSE, no difference.

As long as I don't hard reboot, the laptop is okay for a few days, then it's back to performing a slow startup, usually at the worst time. This will be starting from the users screen, where you select the user then log in.

Is there anything I can use to find out what the laptop is doing for these 15 minutes?

I know there is an existing issue [windows-7-does-not-respond-for-15-minutes-after-start-up](https://superuser.com/questions/647512/windows-7-does-not-respond-for-15-minutes-after-start-up), but it's almost six years old, so hoping there's fresher advice.

- Dell Vostro 3750
- Intel Core i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20 GHz
- 4.00 GB (3.90 GB usable)
- 64-bit OS

Comment: This could be literally anything. Could be faulty hardware such as the harddisk, or a software conflicht. You can narrow it down by looking at events in the eventlog, but other than that, its going to be nearly impossible for us to provide you with an answer.

Comment: Check also the SMART data of the hard disk.